# MongoDB alternative to $exists

Tags: mongodb

I have 100000 documents and I need to retrieve the top 10 documents that have the highest values.

Here's an example of a simplified document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId( "4f2fbeb0369a2ba603000000" ),
    "usage" : {
        "2012" : {
            "2" : {
                "project" : {
                    "4f182a76369a2b2903000000" : {
                        "site" : {
                            "1" : 5,
                            "2" : 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The value that the sort/limit will be applied to can be found in 'usage.2012.2.project.4f182a76369a2b2903000000.site.1' (in the case of the above example, the value is 5).

The problem is that in some documents this object exists, in others it won't.

Now I could use $exists to check if the object exists, but according to the MongoDB manual using $exists is inefficient. Are there any alternative ways that I could go about doing this? I can change the schema if required to suit..

Comment: What should be returned if the object doesn't exist? Can it be excluded from the result set?

Comment: Sorry I should of said. Yes, it should be excluded (should narrow down the 100000 collections to about 1000, then the sort limit will narrow it down to 10).

Comment: What is the query you're running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you query based on a value that does not exist in certain documents, the documents that do not contain the value are excluded from the result set. You should not have to filter them using $exists in advance.

```
db.collection.find().sort( { "usage.2012.2.project.4f182a76369a2b2903000000.site.1" : -1 } ).limit(10)
```

The query above will only return up to 10 values - it will not regard documents where the sorting field doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't believe I can query based on a value as I don't know the value in advance (the overall aim is to return 10 collections that contain the highest numbers), essentially filtered by 2012.2, the project ID and the site ID.

Comment: I may not be understanding completely. Is it the case that you know the 2012.2, the project ID and site ID in advance?

Comment: No problem. Edited my answer above.

Comment: Interesting idea there.. I didn't know about the -1, seems quite useful. Unfortunately I get: 'SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1'. The only way I can get the query to run is the change the sort query to usage:-1, but obviously that's incorrect. Maybe you can't pass dot notation into the sort parameters..

Comment: Sorry - you can use dot notation - just wrap the notation in quotes.  I edited above.

Comment: I'm assuming with "collections" the OP doesn't mean actual MongoDB collections? Very confusing question.

Comment: I am assuming he was referring to documents.

Comment: Apologies, I meant documents! I'll edit the question for future ref. Thanks anyway, it works now!